# Streaming video camera input from WebCamTexture on mobile? (Possibly via WebRTC or websocket?)

Tags: unity, video, mobile

I'm building an application where I stream video camera feed from one mobile device to another in Unity. I tried searching for answers, but most of the topics deal with how to display a video stream, rather than how to send it.

I tried looking for plugins and only found two that do something similar [1](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/68030), [2](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/7447), but they don't provide much information in regards to mobile support and the plugin price is way too steep for my student budget and a non-commercial application.

Another approach I am looking into right now is to try streaming the texture itself, but I haven't figured it out yet. Is there an easier way to stream WebCamTexture content on mobile platforms?